# How remove margin and the application icon in the custom ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-relativelayout, margin, fill-parent

I create an app with custom ActioBar. It works, but not on all devices. On Lenovo ***k990*** it is not correct.  - I am sorry - Lenovo ***k900***

[image]

It should look like this

[image]

First variant

```
 ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar_category, null);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);
    }
```

Second variant

```
  ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_category);
    }
    View actionBarLayout = actionBar.getCustomView();
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = actionBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    actionBarLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Third variant

```
 ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar_main_menu, null);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    if(actionBar!= null){
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setLogo(null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);

        View v = actionBar.getCustomView();
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = v.getLayoutParams(); 
        lp.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        v.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
```

Can you help me?

Comment: A bit more description as to what is the problem on Lenovo K990?

Comment: There is a screenshot  - http://take.ms/rxnfg